# If a Short Exact Sequence is Split-Exact, Does that Mean it is Left-Split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, injective-module

If a short exact sequence is split-exact, can we conclude it is left-split?

**Motivation:** I am asking this question because I want to prove that if every $R$-module is projective, then every $R$-module is injective. I have already proved that if every $R$-module is projective, then the short exact sequence is split-exact. I need to move from there to prove that since we have a short exact sequence, then every $R$-module is injective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma This might help? May be useful to note that the category of $R$-modules is an abelian category (and in fact every abelian category embeds in the category of $R$-modules). But long story short, yes, for $R$-modules, split exact = left exact = right exact

Comment: @OsamaGhani Thanks a lot. I just checked the link. It says if a sequence is left split, then it is split exact. I am not sure it says if a sequence is split exact, then it is left split. Could you help me clarify this?

Comment: It says all 3 are equivalent. If you take split exact to mean "isomorphic to direct sum plus conditions" then there is an "obvious" left splitting, see where it says $ 3 \implies 1$

Comment: @OsamaGhani Oh, I see. I don’t know how I missed that at first. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As linked in the comments by *Osama Ghani*, the relevant result here is the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma). This lemma tells us that a sequence of $R$-modules
$$
0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C\to0
$$
is isomorphic to the trivial short exact sequence
$$
0 \to A \xrightarrow{\operatorname{incl}} A\oplus C \xrightarrow{\operatorname{proj}} C\to0
$$
if and only if there is either $(1)$ a *retraction* of $f$ or $(2)$ a *section* of $g$.

Now, if we fix $C$ on the right, this sequence being split-exact, i.e. every projection onto $C$ having a section, is equivalent to $C$ being projective. Similarly, fixing $A$, every injection from $A$ having a retraction is equivalent to $A$ being injective.

Now consider $A$ arbitrary and an injection $A\hookrightarrow B$. Letting $C=B/A$ we obtain a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to A \to B \to C\to 0\,.
$$
If we assume that *every* $R$-module is projective, in particular $C$ will be projective. Hence the above sequence splits. However, this then also implies that we can find a retraction of $A\to B$, that is, $A$ is injective.